# What is the way to get curves from AcDbRegion?

Tags: autocad, autocad-plugin, objectarx

In the ObjectARX application I'm using `AcDbRegion::createFromCurves` to create a region and works OK.

Now I need to get subentities when I have the `AcDbRegion`. I mean something similar to `AcDbHatch::getLoopAt`

Can anybody point the way to get solution?

Answer (score 1):

you should use `AcDbEntity::explode`

http://help.autodesk.com/view/OARX/2018/ENU/?guid=OREF-AcDbEntity__explode_AcDbVoidPtrArray__const

Comment: `explode ` looks OK, but when I have the region-rectangle with hole-rectangle I will get 8 lines, now I need to check which line is part of inside or outside loop: select one line, get continuations, and compare areas. do You know any simpler way?

Comment: Have a look at the AcBr library. 
http://help.autodesk.com/view/OARX/2018/ENU/?guid=GUID-73B2CF7F-0E2A-445E-9E27-8B622055E14C